# How would you generate missing data using single loop from an array which can contain from 0 to 7 elements?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

So I have an API which returns me the value of water dispensed for the last 7 days and it can contain an empty array or a value such as:

```
[
  {
    day: Monday,
    waterDispensed: 40,
  },
  {
    day: Wednesday,
    waterDispensed: 83,
  },
  {
    day: Thursday,
    waterDispensed: 33,
  },
]
```

Assuming today is Thursday and I need an array of objects which would fill missing last 7 days data as:

```
[
  {
    day: Friday,  // 25th Feb
    waterDispensed: 0,
  },
  {
    day: Saturday, // 26th Feb
    waterDispensed: 0,
  },
  {
    day: Sunday, // 27th Feb
    waterDispensed: 0,
  },
  {
    day: Monday,
    waterDispensed: 40,
  },  
  {
    day: Tuesday,
    waterDispensed: 0,
  },
  {
    day: Wednesday,
    waterDispensed: 83,
  },
  {
    day: Thursday, // 3rd March
    waterDispensed: 33,
  },
]
```

How would you do this considering that you need to use only one loop? You can use conditional statements but not like a newbie.
You can use array methods but should consider time complexity.

Comment: That data structure isn't valid unless the days are actually variables. Also, this smells of a homework assignment which is fine as long as you are showing your work. How do you think you'd do it? What is your attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create an array of the week days you need. For this, you can use an array with the days of the week, double it, and then slice out the part that corresponds to the actual range you need.

Then turn that into an object array with 0 values, and finally overwrite the objects in that array with the objects that you got from the response:

```js
const dayNames = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

function fillWeek(date, data) {
    const weekday = date.getDay();
    const week = dayNames.concat(dayNames).slice(weekday + 1, weekday + 8);
    let result = week.map(day => ({day, waterDispensed: 0 }));
    for (let obj of data) result[week.indexOf(obj.day)] = obj;
    return result;
}

const data = [
  { day: "Monday",    waterDispensed: 40 },
  { day: "Wednesday", waterDispensed: 83 },
  { day: "Thursday",  waterDispensed: 33 },
]
// Let's assume a Thursday (3 March 2022 is a Thursday):
let result = fillWeek(new Date(2022, 2, 3), data);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, can you explain how this line is working?                      
 **for (let obj of data) result[week.indexOf(obj.day)] = obj;**

Comment: Which part of it? Do you understand `for`? Do you understand `result[]`? `indexOf`? ...

Comment: I didn't understand what this line is doing **result[week.indexOf(obj.day)] = obj**

Comment: `obj.day` is the dayname you get from the response. Its index is found in the `week` array we have (which lists all days of the week, but in the order we need for the output). The object at that index is replaced with `obj`, which is what we have in the original response data.

Comment: Thank you so much. Never found someone this kind and helpful. <3